# The Name of Hyperledger Fabric Test Network is not detected by an Application given in the fabric samples

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-network

I just reinstalled Fabric Samples v2.2.0 from Hyperledger Fabric repository according to the [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/install.html).

But when I try to run `asset-transfer-basic` application located in `fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/application-javascript` directory by running `node app.js` the wallet is created and an admin and user is registered. But then it tries to invoke the function as given in `app.js` and shows this error

```
error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    peer=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, status=500, message=error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 
aa705c10403cb65cecbd360c13337d03aac97a8f233a466975773586fe1086f6: could not launch chaincode basic_1.0:b359a077730d7
f44d6a437ad49d1da951f6a01c6d1eed4f85b8b1f5a08617fe7: error starting container: error starting container:
 API error (404): network _test not found
```

[Response of a transaction to invoke a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApusC.png)

This error never occured before. But somehow after reinstalling docker and Hyperledger Fabric `fabric-samples` it never seems to find the network `_test`.

N.B. : Before reinstalling name of the network was `net_test`. But now when I try `docker network ls` it shows a network called `docker_test`. I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) version 1.

```
NETWORK ID     NAME          DRIVER    SCOPE
b7ac05456f46   bridge        bridge    local
acaa5856b871   docker_test   bridge    local
866f58b9078d   host          host      local
4812f94efb15   none          null      local
```

How can I fix the issue occurring when I try to run the application?

Comment: try to bring all the components at a common network, currently, you components are at different network

Comment: Please describe the process. I am new docker user.

Comment: follow the same steps provided in the documentation or refer [this](https://adityaajoshi.medium.com/hyperledger-fabric-2-2-tutorial-eb21618d5fa)

Comment: personally I would stop trying to use wsl 1 to do this, it is going to present interesting challenges. You would be far better off using wsl 2 to begin with.

Comment: I followed this process every time but the same error is occurring

Comment: But my files are mounted on windows file system.

Comment: Could you check the peer's `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` variable?

Comment: where can I find `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` variable?

Comment: I explained it in detail as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, the `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` setting seems to be wrong. 
you can check `docker-compose.yaml` or `core.yaml`

#### 1. docker-compose.yaml

- I will explain fabric-samples/test-network as targeting according to your current situation.
- You can check in `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` in docker-compose.yaml
- Perhaps in your case(fabric-samples/test-network), the value of `${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}` was not set properly, so it was set to `_test`.
- Make sure the value is set correctly and change it to your network name.

```yaml
# hyperledger/fabric-samples/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml
# based v2.2
...
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.2
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_test
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=docker_test
...
```

---

#### 2. core.yaml

If you have not set the value in the `docker-compose.yaml` peer, you need to check the `core.yaml` referenced by the peer.

you can find the `networkMode` parameter in `core.yaml`

```yaml
# core.yaml
...
vm:
    docker:
        hostConfig:
            # NetworkMode: host
            NetworkMode: docker_test
...
```

---

If neither is set, it will be set to the default value. However, as you see `_test` being logged, the wrong value have been set in one of the two section, and you need to correct the value to the value you intended.

Comment: I changed the value of `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` variable in my `docker-compose-test-net.yaml` file from `${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_test` to `docker_test` and the application was able to find the `docker_test` network. I changed both the files. But later when I redo the change in `core.yaml` the application still worked.

Comment: `core.yaml` is the value set when the initial peer bootstrap, and if an environment variable is set, it will be overwritten with the environment variable. In other words, if both are set, they are set to the env value of `docker-compose.yaml`. I'm so glad your problem was solved.

Comment: It was very helpful to know about these files. Is there any resource/documentation which can be helpful to understand the contents of the `.yaml` files which comes with `fabric-samples`?

Comment: I don't know if it will help. In my case, I understood it by comparing the code with the content introduced in the official document.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is related to docker networking. In complete to @nezuko-response.

Create a file and name it **".env"** in the same directory where your docker-compose file exists.
Add the following line in it:

> COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=net

Use `docker-compose up` to update the container with the new configurations.

Or bring the HL network down (`./network.sh down`) and up (`./network.sh up`), restarting the **test-nework**.

Otherwise you'll still get the same error even after creating **".env"** file.

More explanation about [docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Answer (score 2):

run `./network down`
then

```
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=net
```

afterwards

```
./network start
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied this from someone .This one worked for me !!

Please create a file named ".env" in the same directory where your docker-compose file exists. Add the following line in ".env" file:-

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=net
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```html
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=net
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).