# Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction

Tags: hyperledger

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 4a5ed9609bd32b32c59d3208f93cb746db489f850040fa6e6f2853c21a18084e: 
could not launch chaincode basic_1.0:4ec191e793b27e953ff2ede5a8bcc63152cecb1e4c3f301a26e22692c61967ad: error starting container: error starting container: API error (404): network _test not found"
```

When i try to initialize the ledger with assets i got above error. I'm new to blockchain, i have no idea why i received such error.

Comment: see below link, [stackoverflow-hlf-network-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65932112/the-name-of-hyperledger-fabric-test-network-is-not-detected-by-an-application-gi/65948617#65948617)